# Is there a way to override the default behavior of parenthesis?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to overload the operator `,` so that I can assign my fraction using this syntax:
`frac = 1, 2`. It worked fine without `()` operators.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class fraction {
private:
    int m_num;
    int m_den;

public:
    fraction(int num, int den) 
        :m_num(num), m_den(den) {

    }

    fraction& operator =(int num) {
        m_num = num;
        return *this;
    }

    fraction& operator ,(int den) {
        m_den = den;
        return *this;
    }

public:
    friend 
        ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const fraction& rhs) {
        return out << rhs.m_num << ", " << rhs.m_den;
    }
};

int main() {
    fraction f(1, 2);   
    cout << "original f = " << f << endl;

    f = 4, 5;
    cout << "expected = " << f << endl;

    f = (10, 11);
    cout << "unexpected = " << f << endl;
}
```

**OUTPUT

```
$ prog.exe
original f = 1, 2
expected = 4, 5
unexpected = 11, 5
```

I accidentally put a `()` around `num` and `den`, and from the output I realized the precedence of `operator ()` affected the actual result. It evaluated using only `operator ,` which is odd. So my question is, is there a way (macro maybe?) to ignore the affect of operator `()` in this particular situation?

Comment: There is no `operator()` here.

Comment: No, it evaluated only `operator=`, using the default `operator,`. That's what happens when you use parenthesis. And there isn't a way to do what you want (or if there is, you shouldn't).

Comment: Omg. It has been a long time since I have seen a case of operator overloading abuse.

Comment: Overloading operators this way is usually a bad idea.  You should define operators to do the same thing as a person with no knowledge of your library would expect.  + should do addition/concatenation, / should do division, etc.  Redefining comma like this makes your code confusing to most anyone the first time they look at it.

Comment: Also, you should avoid overloading `operator,` for precisely this kind of reason (see also Item 7 of Scott Meyers' "*More Effective C++*").

Comment: Well, I just want to have fun with C++ syntax. Anyway, thanks guys.

Comment: @Oil Charlesworth: I meant to say `parenthesis`. My bad!

Comment: There is no way to do exactly what you are asking, but you may find it interesting that in C++11, you can use f = {4,5} (braces instead of parentheses) without overloading any operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only overload operators when at least one of the arguments is user-defined.  In your case, both of your arguments would be `int`s, so there's nothing you can do.

(Other than avoiding questionable usage of `operator,`!)